# GenerateUserIdentity in this method i need to get current domain name as based on domain name i need to add claim value. Asp.net 4.5 Framework

Tags: claims-based-identity

`public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)`
in this method i need to add domain name in identity claim.

this method called from 2 places 1 is startup.auth as below.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
// Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
// This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity\<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser\>(
validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) =\> user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
}
});
```

2nd is from identityConfig

```
public override Task\<ClaimsIdentity\> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager,this.subdomain);
}
```

Please let me know what to do.
I have used inbuilt Asp.net identity structure.

I want domain name in claim identity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.